# Update value of existing gauge having dynamic tags

Tags: prometheus, counter, metrics, gauge, micrometer

when I try to update value of existing gauge, unable to do since the metric is already registered and we cannot re-register the same gauge metric.

Comment: Please consider adding code samples demonstrating what you have attempted to do, and perhaps a sample of the expected output/results.

Comment: private MeterRegistry registry; 

public void registerMetricsAndSetValue(String country, String state, long population) (
AtomicLong gauge = registry.gauge("PopulationPerCountryPerState", Tags.of("COUNTRY", country, 'STATE", state), new AtomicLong(0));
gauge.set(population);

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic tags would represent differing gauges. The simplest approach is to have the gauge point to an object holding the value to be updated, an `AtomicDouble` would suffice.

Comment: I have added the code snippet I am using, similar to what you suggest but it never updates the value.

Comment: Move your snippet into the question. You'll need to store the `AtomicLong` outside your method so it stays around long term.

Answer (score 0):

```
gauge = meterRegistry.get("name").tags("tagkey1","tagValue1").gauge();
        if (gauge == null) {
          Gauge nameGauge = Gauge.builder("name", list, List::size)
              .tags("tagkey1","tagValue1")
              .description("message")
              .register(meterRegistry);
        }else{
          meterRegistry.gauge("name", Tags.of("tagkey1","tagValue1"), sizeValue);
        }
```